# Why everyone uses unsafe content security policy?

Tags: javascript, http-headers

I see that all big websites like Google or Facebook, even my bank uses content-security-policy header with unsafe-eval and unsafe-inline. Is there point in using csp if such big companies disable it? Are there big websites that use csp without unsafe scripts?

Comment: Content Security Policies are pretty new.   I just read [this article about them](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) so that I'd have some idea what we are talking about here. In my experience, inline scripts are very important for performance.   I would have a very hard time modifying my existing websites to not use them, and then the websites would be slower.

Answer (score 1):

CSP can protect website visitors from malicious hackers but it can also rip apart the web design and mangle code like noscript and tidy and this could also expose your website's errors and other website information. So make sure you cross your T's and dot your i's.